# Boolean var has different value then query filling it?

Tags: java, user-interface, boolean, vaadin

Alright guys, I'm absolutely speechless. I am building a GUI with the vaadin framework, but that shouldn't matter for the problem. Heres my Code:

```
private final boolean readOnly = GenericAdapterFrontendApplication
        .getInstance().getUserRole().equals(UserRole.READ);

public InstitutionDetailMasterData(Institution i) {
    super(i);
}

protected void createSectionContent(Institution i, Panel p) {
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata." + PROP_NAME),
            i.getName()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_DEUBA_ID), i.getDeubaId()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(ViewUtils
            .getMessage("view.institut.masterdata." + PROP_VARIANT), i
            .getVariant().toString()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_FIELD_SEP), i.getFieldSeparator()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_RECORD_SEP), i.getRecordSeparator()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_DATE_FORMAT), i.getDateFormat()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_DECIMAL_SEP), i.getDecimalSeparator()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_THOUSAND_SEP), i.getThousandSeparator()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(ViewUtils
            .getMessage("view.institut.masterdata." + PROP_QUOTING), i
            .getQuoting()));
    p.addComponent(createRow(
            ViewUtils.getMessage("view.institut.masterdata."
                    + PROP_FREQUENCY), i.getFrequency()));
    System.out.println(GenericAdapterFrontendApplication
            .getInstance().getUserRole().equals(UserRole.READ));
    System.out.println(this.readOnly);
    editButton.setVisible(!this.readOnly);
```

Now the important parts are the declaration of readOnly at the beginning and both prints ath the end, because thy print:

```
true
false
```

How is that even possible? I mean I could work with the direct query to set the button visibility but it bothers me that those values seem impossible to me. If anyone has an idea for explanation please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Could the value be changing at runtime? The member variable declaration will be assigned when the class is instantiated, whereas the value in your println statement will be evaluated each time that method is called. Depending on the object lifecycle in this framework, maybe your class is instantiated before the GenericAdapterFrontendApplication is properly setup for use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class attribute `readonly` is assigned when the object is instantiated.

If this happens as part of the application initialisation - *before* a user has signed on - it could have a different value when `createSectionContent` is called.

Assuming that it is not costly to access the user's state, I would suggest that you do not store it as an attribute, but rather create a `isReadOnly()` method that calls the method on demand, e.g.

```
protected boolean isReadOnly(){
    return GenericAdapterFrontendApplication.getInstance().getUserRole().equals(UserRole.READ);
}
```

If it is costly, lazy initialize it.

Comment: Yeah I think that's it. So I'm gonna change it to the isReadOnly()-Method like you said or pass the UserRole as a parameter, I'll see. 
Thanks, eyerybody!

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is the execution order. readOnly is assigned earlier and the state might have changed after that.